# Multible dynamic URLs in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

Making a clinic website, in which the user is the clinics, who can then create "patient" objects. To navigate the page, I want the URLs to be dynamic and specific for the clinic and the given patient.
Im having trouble making a selecting button on the clinics dashboard. The Dashboard has the following URL: `/<str:kl_id>/` . the button should link to a patient page with the URL:

```
/<str:kl_id>/patientside/<str:pt_id>/
```

The Views.py file looks like this:

```
def klinik(request, kl_id):
    klinik = Klinik.objects.all()
    kliniknavn = Klinik.objects.get(navn=kl_id)
    E_patient = kliniknavn.patient_set.all()
    context = {'E_patient':E_patient, 'klinik':klinik}
    return render(request,'DentHelp/klinik.html', context )
```

I have tried in the template to make the following code, making a list of eksisting patients, with buttons leading to the dynamic patient page:

```
{% for patient in E_patient %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{patient.id_nr}}</td>
    <td>{{patient.fornavn}}</td>
    <td><a href="{% url 'patientside' kl_id=klinik.navn pt_id=patient.id_nr %}" class="btn btn-primary">Vælg patient</a></td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

edit:

Models in use:

```
class Klinik(models.Model):
navn = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

class Patient(models.Model):
id_nr= models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
klinik = models.ForeignKey(Klinik, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

With this code do I get a NoReverseMatch error when trying the klinik page.
Looking forward to getting help.

Comment: `klinik.navn` does it contain id ?

Comment: I'll suggest to use [`get-absolute-url()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) also share your models

Comment: Have made an edit to reveal Models in use

Comment: Doesn't `{% url` require `'appname:patientside'` ? Also check the name on the url for a silly typo :-)